# ¿Dónde está la carpeta temporal que usa Laravel para upload files?

Tags: laravel, archivo, upload

Estoy intentando cambiar la manera en que utilizo la función move() de la clase "File" moviendo ficheros desde el dir tmp para mover el fichero subido por post a una carpeta del proyecto.

Cuando uso el método segun la API de Laravel:

```
$dir = $request->input('imagen');
$dir->move(storage_path().'/'.tmp);
```

Esto funciona correctamente. ¿Qué problema tengo?

Si quiero hacer estas operaciones en una Queue, recibo error de serializatión, no me permite pasar una variable de este tipo al job, por lo tanto se me ocurre la idea de pasar únicamente la dirección del fichero temporal y moverla desde el job.

Envio la url al job:

```
$file->getPathName();
```

Lo paso al job, y desde el job hago la misma operacion pero en lugar de usar $dir->move, uso File::move($url_temporal,storage_path().'/'.$nombre);.

Y siempre da el mismo error, no se encuentra el fichero o directorio.

Creo que el problema es que la url siempre es de formato "/tmp/jadfuyg" pero nunca he visto en la carpeta temporal del sistema ningun fichero subido por laravel.

¿Dónde se encuentra la carpeta temporal que usa laravel?

PD: He probado a cambiar permisos a tmp dir del sistema (uso ubuntu), también a añadir al grup www-data por si fuera por ese tema, pero no hay cambios.

Comment: hay un archivo llamado filesystem.php, hay lo tienes que especificar

Comment: @EduBw pero actualmente está usando un "/tmp" y cuando uso el primera comando todo funciona correctamente, quieres decir que en el fichero filesystem.php estará la ubicación?

Comment: Su raíz es la carpeta public, pero si usas getPathName(), lo defines en filesystem.php en Dir

Comment: @EduBw El método getPathname() devuelve el dir del fichero , pero no de laravel, es una función php en realidad y me devuelve '/tmp' . Y el error que me da o bien es por tema permisos (aunque he probado a cambiar permisos 777 y chown www-data al dir /tmp del sistema para probar) o bien '/tmp' hace referencia a otro directorio.
http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getpathname.php

Comment: Si, perdón, quería copiarte el storage_path() que lo guardará donde lo definas en filesystem.php en donde dice dir. si te da error captura con try catch y mira lo que te dice, quizás es problema del tamaño del archivo, que entonces deberás cambiarlo en el php.ini

Comment: @EduBw Gracias ara entiendo, si si funciona correctamente, de hecho me he creado un dir dentro de storage_path() llamado tmp y los muevo allí, el problema viene cuando quiero hacer lo mismo osea esto: $dir = $request->input('imagen');
$dir->move(storage_path().'/'.tmp); pero en lugar de $dir->move(), hacer File::move(aquí el path del temporal,storage_path('tmp')); y esto lo necesito hacer porqué no me deja pasar una variable $request hacia una queue